# How to append to an array on another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I have an array in a tableView that shows that contents of that array, and I am able to append values to the array. the problem is that whenever I go to another page, it automatically empties, but I want the values to stay there. Here is my code for the first view controller:

```
//  AddFoodViewController.swift
//  grosseries
//
//  Created by Amish Tyagi on 6/2/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 grosseries. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class AddFoodViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var foodTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func doneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func transitionToNext() {
        let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toTableViewController") {
            let homeViewController = segue.destination as? TableViewController
            homeViewController?.food.append(foodTextField.text!)
            view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my second view controller:

```
//  TableViewController.swift
//  grosseries
//
//  Created by Amish Tyagi on 5/29/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 grosseries. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var food : [String]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
    @IBAction func addItemTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        transitionToNext()
    }
    func transitionToNext() {
        let nextViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AddFoodViewController") as? AddFoodViewController

        view.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

extension TableViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("you tapped me :)")
    }
}


extension TableViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = food[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


}
```

Here is a picture of my storyboard layout: [image: Storyboard Layout]
Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Either use segues or instantiate controllers. But don't use both simultaneously.

Comment: Sure, but any ideas on how to fix this problem? (Not trying to be rude)

Comment: I could save the array using only the segue to instantiate controllers as @vadian mentioned. Try it and see if works.

Comment: @paulRick, I tried that, but still doesn't work. Look at edit above.

Comment: You have two viewControllers, one to add a food, and the other to display the food added. You can go forward and backwards on both views. Did I get it right? Because, as I see, your foods' array is in the `AddFoodViewController` and each time you "go back to it" you are instantiate a new one inside `transitionToNext()` hence losing all previous foods added. What I would do is set a NavigationController and instead of instantiating a new controller each time just use segues to go forward, the navigation do the work on backwards.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I have another food array in TableViewController that I am appending to, should I do the same thing anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard, select your `TableViewController` storyboard and select Editor->Embed in->Navigation Controller:

[image]

Below your tableView (or anywhere else you'd like) add a button with a segue to show the `AddFoodViewController`.

Now, on your `AddFoodViewController` add a button to confirm the food you put on textField:

```
@IBAction func confirmAddedFood(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let tableViewVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? TableViewController else { return }
    tableViewVC.food.append(foodTextField.text!)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

You don't need the food array on your `AddFoodViewController` anymore, you still need the one on `TableViewController` though.

Don't forget to reload the tableView when you go back to it after adding a food, in your `TableViewController` add:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yeah... Table View Controller comes first, and then AddFoodViewController... Should I do the same thing just with Table View Controller?

Comment: First TableViewController loads and then it goes to AddFoodViewController and then back to TableViewController where it shows whatever that has been appended.

Comment: So instead of adding the NavigationController to `AddFoodViewController` you add it to `TableViewController`. See edited answer.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, whenever I press done nothing happpens

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your `TableViewController`:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var food: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // In the case when not using prototype cell.
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = food[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

And `FoodViewController`:

```
class AddFoodViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var foodTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func confirmAddedFood(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let tableViewVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? TableViewController else { return }
        tableViewVC.food.append(foodTextField.text!)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

It's not very cool to just give the already done code, but I think in this case is just a silly mistake, whether from you or me.

Comment: When you are using a navigation controller it should have a back button, but for me there is just black space for my AddViewController. I think it is not connected to the navigation controller and therefore when I press done nothing happens. This may have something to do with the navigation controller not being the first view controller (A.K.A. connected to the storyboard entry point). Also, It may be because I am instantiating the TableViewController from another view controller. In my edit, I have my whole storyboard layout.

Comment: How are you instantiating the TableViewController? Instead of instantiating the TableViewController itself try instantiating the NavigationController that is attached to it. Like: `let view = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "nav")`

Comment: When I do that, the screen just goes black.. any fixes for that?

Comment: Is it black when you set the TableViewController's NavigationController as the initial view? You could add the NavigationController to that "WeekDaysController" instead of the TableViewController.

Comment: Its still black even if I instantiate the navigation controller... Is it possible to do it using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I got it to work using NSUserDefualts and using another swift file to save my food array. Each time I instantiate TableViewController, I update the userDefault.